# defining an initial variable in a new object in php

Tags: php

I am new to OOP so forgive me if my question is flawed.

I am writing a class to fetch and populate a data set, this will be performed within a loop, which will return a series of index id's by which I will populate the data of the object. Within the app, I will need to both do this in a loop, and individually. My question is when (inside or outside the loop) I initiate the class, how would I define the id for that particular object's item id, which will be used by the class's methods?

```
$object = New item($itemid);
// or
$object = New item->4;
// ?
```

I am not sure how to do this, or if this is even the proper way to handle this kind of logic.

*sidenote*

*I am writing this class under the assumption that my first object will be a collection of commonly used functions that currently only exist as such, so just trying to clean things up.*

Comment: Please, start by reading the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Since you're new to OOP, you should usually use getter and setter methods to assign and get values from your object. (Not directly accessing them). Just a heads up

Comment: You write a class to hold some functions. That is merely class based programming and not OOP (it can be fine though). I just write this because it is often healthier in the long run to differ between these two. If you move global functions into that class, make the class abstract so that it can not be instantiated and make the functions static. That should help you to keep a cleaner line between OOP and class based programming. One term you might run over more often then is [*Utility Class*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the class, and then set the item id.

```
$object = new item();
$object->item_id = 1;
```

Comment: Or, use the __construct() function to take the parameter of item_id if it is always set when the class is initialised, and set it from within the __construct() function.

Comment: Assuming the variable is public. Also intialisation should be done in the constructor.

Comment: Ok so my thinking was if I initiated it without defining that it would cause an error, but the classes' methods aren't executed until called from the object itself. That makes sense. Would my case above be a good example to use a constructor? @RMcLeod answered that.

Answer (score 4):

The first way

```
class Item {
    private $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}

$object = new Item($itemid);
```

Try to use private member variables where you can and set them with the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for that. 
Example:

```
<?php           
  class person {
     public $name;
     public function __construct($persons_name) {           
       $this->name = $persons_name;            
     }
    // ....   rest
}
```

Now, when you create the object with `new` keyword, pass the arguments.

```
<?php 
  $user = new person('Ayesh K);
```

Otherwise you can explicitly set values for the class as well.